# Access dynamic AVG query based on filter

Tags: sql, ms-access, dynamic, average

I've the following table called tblX:

| id | type | nr |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Z | 3 |
| 2 | Y | 3 |
| 3 | X | 3 |
| 4 | X | 5 |
| 5 | Z | 6 |
| 6 | X | 2 |

I've the following query called qryX based on the table tblX

| id | type | nr | total_avg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Z | 3 | 3.66 |
| 2 | Y | 3 | 3.66 |
| 3 | X | 3 | 3.66 |
| 4 | X | 5 | 3.66 |
| 5 | Z | 6 | 3.66 |
| 6 | X | 2 | 3.66 |

The SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT tblX.*, DAvg("nr","tblX") AS total_avg
FROM tblX;
```

When I'm filtering the data in the query bases on type X I would like the following total_avg result

| id | type | nr | total_avg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | X | 3 | **3.33** |
| 4 | X | 5 | **3.33** |
| 6 | X | 2 | **3.33** |

Instead of 3.33 it gives the originally 3.66.

How can I adjust the aggregated function DAvg("nr","tblX") to be dynamic?

I've been searching for a while but most of the solutions were only for power bi.

The goal is to centralize my calculations in a query instead of multiple separated calculation fields in forms and reports!

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```sql
SELECT 
    tblX.*, 
    DAvg("nr", "tblX", "[type] = '" & [type] & "'") AS total_avg
FROM 
    tblX;
```

Comment: Sorry, I wish the AVG (3+5+2)/3 = 3.33. Tnx for the solution. But what if I'm filtering on an other new field? Is it possible to get the filter criteria?

Comment: See corrected answer, please. The filter in `DAvg` can be adjusted as you like.

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work. I now get the average per type. It must change completely dynamically based on the filter.

Comment: _I now get the average per type_  ... and that was what you asked for. Adjust the filter if you wish something else.

Comment: Then I have not been able to express my wish properly. My wish is a dynamic query, not a static one. If the filter is off or altered the result has to adjust automatically. Now, when the filter is off I still get the average per type, in this case I need the average of all records...

Comment: Oh, but SQL cannot be dynamic. If you wish something like that, you must have some code that adjusts or rewrites the SQL before running the query.

Comment: That's to bad. In a form (calculated field) it works like a charm...

Comment: By way of correction: the result must change dynamically. Ofcourse is the SQL static ...

Comment: I have to admit, that what you are trying to achieve is fading.